# Fusion Two dataframes into one dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframes DATA_DF and TAUX_DF. I use a condition to select data from TAUX_DF and put it into a new field on DATA_DF
For this i use `DATA_DF['Taux technique']=(indexed_TAUX_DF.loc[DATA_DF['Date effet'].dt.year.where(DATA_DF['Duree (Mois)']>120),['>10 ans']]).values`

i have as a [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm15N.png)
[image: more than 10 years values]

This column contains many nan values .I want to fill those nan values by another Dataframe which contains another values in the place of nan values.
I use this but it doesnt work`DATA_DF['Taux technique'].fillna(indexed_TAUX_DF.loc[DATA_DF['Date effet'].dt.year.where(DATA_DF['Duree (Mois)']<120),['<10 ans']])`

[This is picture of TAUX_DF not indexed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fpdM.png)
[image]
I have an error

> ValueError: invalid fill value with a class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
>   DATA_DF['Duree (Mois)'] is the number of months in the period that i use a function to have it `DATA_DF['Date effet'].DATA_DF['Date fin effet'].dt.month`
>   in TAUX_DF we have the rate of every period Example if we have period less than 10 years on 2014 we should have the result 0.34600
>   for this i have to select data if we have period less than 120 month we select the column ['<10 ans'] or opposite and store those results on a one column on DATA_DF['Taux technique'] 
>   When i use `indexed_TAUX_DF.loc[DATA_DF['Date effet'].dt.year.where(DATA_DF['Duree (Mois)']<120),['<10 ans']]`and `indexed_TAUX_DF.loc[DATA_DF['Date effet'].dt.year.where(DATA_DF['Duree (Mois)']>120),['>10 ans']]`i have to dataframes which contains nan values opposites [for less than 10 years values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md6Ky.png)

Comment: this looks wrong `['<10 ans']` as the alternate fill value what are you intending to fill when the condition is `False`?

Comment: On TAUX_DF i have two columns TAUX_DF['<10 ans']  and TAUX_DF['>10 ans'] which containes percentages that i want to select if the period is less than 10 years or opposite I'm sure that there are a value . Just i want that DATA_DF['Taux technique'] contains both of values indexed_TAUX_DF.loc[DATA_DF['Date effet'].dt.year.where(DATA_DF['Duree (Mois)']<120),['<10 ans']] and indexed_TAUX_DF.loc[DATA_DF['Date effet'].dt.year.where(DATA_DF['Duree (Mois)']>120),['>10 ans']]

Comment: in that case pass `TAUX_DF['<10 ans']` then, what you've passed is a list containing a string

Comment: I use this in excel by vlookup =SI(G2>120;RECHERCHEV(ANNEE(C2);Taux!$A$2:$C$29;3;FAUX);RECHERCHEV(ANNEE(C2);Taux!$A$2:$C$29;2;FAUX))

Comment: Also can you post some sample raw data and code to create both dfs and show what the desired output should be, it's difficult for people to understand and reproduce by looking at images

Comment: Ok i already edited my question thank you my friend